# How to calculate the days between two date columns using eval function of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let I have two date columns .

```
df =    ColA         ColB
       31-1-17      01-2-17

exp = 'days = ColA - ColB'

df.eval(exp,inplace=True)
```

expected output :

```
ColA         ColB      days
31-1-17      01-2-17    1 days
```

I can calculate like this

```
df['days'] = df['ColA'] - df[ColB]
```

but i want to calculate using "eval function" not like the above .

Comment: eval return `ValueError: unknown type timedelta64[ns]`

Comment: or not implemented yet.

Comment: @MaxU: Not a bug. See my answer.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

***new soln:*** (Refer Data section for setup)

Supply `engine='python'` as it's currently set at `engine='numexpr'`. This is because [**`df.eval`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval) inherits it's `kwargs` from [**`pd.eval`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval.)

```
df.eval("days=abs(ColA-ColB)", engine='python', inplace=True)
df
```

[image]

---

***old soln:***

Here's a way to do that: *(tested in `v'0.19.2'`)*

1) Make sure both the columns are of type `datetime64[ns]` first. If not, type-cast them by using `pd.to_datetime` either individually or with the help of `apply`. Here, I've parsed them as `dates` while reading itself to avoid doing this step.

2) Using built-in function `repr()`, convert these to their official representation of a datetime object which could be then understood by the `eval()` function later. 
(As in `repr(datetime.date.today())` gives `'datetime.date(2017, 2, 1)'`)

3) Subtract them by accessing their `.date` attribute and take it's modulus later outputted in days.

---

***Data:***

```
txt = StringIO(
    """
ColA         ColB
31-1-17      01-2-17
    """)
df = pd.read_csv(txt, delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=['ColA', 'ColB'], dayfirst=True)
```

[image]

```
df.assign(days=
          df.apply(lambda x: abs(eval(repr(x['ColA'].date()-x['ColB'].date()))), axis=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I tried simulating the same using python's built-in `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like so:

```
# import pandas as pd
#df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=True ), axis=1)
df.assign(days = lambda x: df.ColB - df.ColA)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible using "eval function" ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval`:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['ColA'] = pd.date_range('01/01/2010', periods=5, freq='M')
>>> df['ColB'] = pd.date_range('01/01/2011', periods=5)
>>> df['days'] = df.eval('ColA-ColB')
>>> df
        ColA       ColB      days
0 2010-01-31 2011-01-01 -335 days
1 2010-02-28 2011-01-02 -308 days
2 2010-03-31 2011-01-03 -278 days
3 2010-04-30 2011-01-04 -249 days
4 2010-05-31 2011-01-05 -219 days
```

This assumes that the contents in `ColA` and `ColB` are `datetime` objects. If not you should convert them first as per MYGz's anwer.

Comment: What is your Pandas version? I'm getting `ValueError: unknown type timedelta64[ns]` using Pandas 0.19.2 (Python 3.5.2)...

Comment: I am also getting the same ValueError: unknown type timedelta64[ns] using pandas 0.18.1 and python 2.7 .

Comment: Weird, works for me both on pandas 0.18.1 and 0.19.2 (Python 3.5.2). This seems to be officially unsupported though: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5007